# How many inflection points are there in the graph?

Tags: calculus

[image]

**Answer:**

Since $f'(x)$ has $5$ concave parts at $x=-2, \ x=-1, \ x=0, \ x=1, \ x=2$.

So are there $5$ inflection points?

Comment: No.  You did not count the inflection points of f.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I believe you are considering the graph to be of $f(x)$ rather than $f'(x)$. The answer by Devashish Kaushik, and the updated answer by B. Goddard, state there are actually $5$ inflection points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I count 6 inflections points.  (But the graph is a little blurry.)  There is one at approximately $x=1/2$ where the graph changes from being concave down to concave up. There is another at $x=3/2$ where the graph changes from concave up to concave down.  Then (if I'm seeing the blurry parts right) there is another at $x=5/2$ where the concavity changes again.

An inflection point is where a graph (smoothly) changes concavity.  So there are three more points on the negative $x$-axis.  An inflection point is also (and more properly) defined as a point where the tangent line crosses the graph.

Edit:  I missed that the graph was of $f'(x)$ rather than $f(x)$.   If the slope is increasing, the graph of $f(x)$ is concave up.  If the slope is decreasing, the graph is concave down.   So at each max or min point of $f'(x)$ the slope changes from increasing to decreasing or the other way.  Since there are $5$ such place, that's how many inflection points there are.

Comment: It seems to me that you're treating the graph as being of $f(x)$ rather than $f'(x)$ as it's labeled.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  You're correct.  Stand by....

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point)

> A differentiable function has an inflection point at (x, f(x)) if and only if its first derivative, f′, has an isolated extremum at x.

Since, $f'$ has local maxima/minima *only* at the points named by you(as per the graph), they are the required points of inflexion and **you are correct**.

Note, that the asymptotic portions are, well asymptotic (to the X-axis), so they can give no extra extrema (while the domain is real).